# FormField DropDownList height

Tags: c#, html, html-select

I want to know how to set the height property for the HTML `<select>` in code.

I tried setting `.Attribute.Add("Style","Height:120px")` just to see if I could get it to change but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Better yet, give it a CssClass. :)

Answer (score 0):

Style is already a Property...

```
DropDownList myDropDown;
myDropDown.Style["height"] = "120px";
```